# How to add an asset to all Shopify pages?

Tags: javascript, php, shopify

I'm trying to add a piece of javascript code to all shopify frontend pages. The problem is, that my code is generated individually for each store. I've figured out that I can do this by `asset`.

```
    $arguments = array(
        "asset" => array(
            "key" => "templates\/index.liquid",
            "value" => "<script>alert('foo')</script>",
        )
    );

    $updateTheme = $shopify('PUT', '/admin/themes/'.$theme_id.'/assets.json', $arguments);
```

But it works only for specific pages. In this case [index.liquid](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/theme-development/templates/index-liquid) can modify only homepage.

I think that [theme.liquid](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/theme-development/layouts/theme-liquid) would do the job but unfortunately it doesn't work.

For my code would be best if he were put in the footer or in header.
Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do a bit more clearly? I may have a solution.

Comment: Well, I'm trying to add javascript to all shopify store pages trough the api (I'm app developer). The problem Is that my script is generated with different parameter for each store during the app installation. Actually I think I found a little bit different solution (for now It's work). Instead of `asset` I've used `ScriptTag` with a little hack which let's me pass variable as parameter to the script. And for now It's much better solution.

Comment: you should have a snippet in your theme called footer.liquid or something like that. you could put your code in there.